# Why can't access my gRPC REST service that is running in Minikube?

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, minikube

I've been learning Kubernetes recently and just came across this small issue. For some sanity checks, here is the functionality of my grpc app running locally:

```
> docker run -p 8080:8080 -it olamai/simulation:0.0.1
  < omitted logs >
> curl localhost:8080/v1/todo/all
{"api":"v1","toDos":[{}]}
```

So it works! All I want to do now is deploy it in Minikube and expose the port so I can make calls to it. My end goal is to deploy it to a GKE or Azure cluster and make calls to it from there (again, just to learn and get the hang of everything.)
[Here is the yaml I'm using to deploy to minikube](https://github.com/OlamAI/Simulation/blob/v2/k8s/deployment.yaml)

And this is what I run to deploy it on minikube

```
> kubectl create -f deployment.yaml
```

I then run this to get the url

```
> minikube service sim-service --url
http://192.168.99.100:30588
```

But this is what happens when I make a call to it

```
> curl http://192.168.99.100:30588/v1/todo/all
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 30588: Connection refused
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: I figured it out, and you should be able to see the update in the linked file. I had pull policy set to Never so it was out of date

I have a new question now... I'm now able to just create the deployment in minikube (no NodePort) and still make calls to the api... shouldn't the deployment need a NodePort service to expose ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your yaml file and it works just fine. But only I realized that you put 2 types for your services, `LoadBalancer` and also `NodePort` which is not needed. 
As if you check from [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) definition of LoadBalancer, you will see

> [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer): Exposes the service externally using a cloud provider’s
>   load balancer. NodePort and ClusterIP services, to which the external
>   load balancer will route, are automatically created.

As an answer for your next question, you probably put `type: LoadBalancer` to your deployment yaml file, that's why you are able to see NodePort anyway.
If you put `type: ClusterIP` to your yaml, then service will be exposed only within cluster, and you won't able to reach to your service outside of cluster.

From same [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types):

> ClusterIP: Exposes the service on a cluster-internal IP. Choosing this
>   value makes the service only reachable from within the cluster. This
>   is the default ServiceType

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, a quick question though. If I want to access a service externally, is setting it's type to NodePort enough or do I need LoadBalancer (Which if I'm understanding correctly sets up a NodePort too)?

Comment: You can reach to your service externally via LoadBalancer also via NodePort. Check this https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport for better understanding about NodePort and LoadBalancer